# Cyclicity of composition operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, chaos

Let $E=C([0,1]^m,\mathbb{R}^n)$ where $K=[0,1]^m$ where $E$ has the [compact convergence topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence).  Recall that for a function $f:[0,1]^m\rightarrow [0,1]^m$ the associated composition operator $C_f$ is defined by
$$
\begin{aligned}
C_f:E &\rightarrow E\\
g &\mapsto g\circ f.
\end{aligned}
$$
We recall that $C_f$ is call [cylic](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Cyclic_vector) if there is some $g^f\in E$ such that $\operatorname{span}\{g^f\circ f^n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is dense in $E$.
Lastly, let $L(E)$ denote the space of bounded linear operators on $E$ with the [weak operator topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_operator_topology).

Is the span of the set of composition operators $C_f$ for which $f$ is cylic, dense in $L(E)$?  If yes, what about if it instead has the strong operator topology?

Comment: On the space $E$, a composition operator $C_f$ is never hypercyclic since it is always power-bounded.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm afraid I still don't understand the question, though. The set of *all* composition operators (no matter whether cyclic or not) is clearly not dense in $L(E)$.

Comment: @JochenGlueck Ah, I mean its span.  Hmm, it seems this question has been plagued with typos.  Hopefully it's polished now.